# How to compile .java file from within java program

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling external .java files from within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889186/compiling-external-java-files-from-within-java)

I have been using examples from all over the net but I keep getting NullPointerExceptions when invoking the run method in JavaCompiler. If you know how to compile another java file from within a java file please provide code on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Post what you're doing and then we can find out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I already used JavaCompiler to compile math expressions on the fly.

Here is how I did it:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("YouFileToCompile.java"));
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null,
        null, compilationUnits);
boolean success = task.call();
fileManager.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for the STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/#seealso) (which uses the `JavaCompiler`).

> The docs for `getSystemJavaCompiler()` mention that it returns **"the compiler provided with this platform or `null` if no compiler is provided"**, but do not make clear why it might be `null`, nor the fact that the compiler will not be available to applets or webstart apps. ..

It will be `null` if the code is run in a non SDK JRE (see explanation in the [System Requirements](http://pscode.org/stbc/#minimumrequirement)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse jdt compiler (http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core). It is used in many projects to compile java.

Here is an example how tomcat uses it to compile servlets to .class: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/jasper/compiler/JDTCompiler.java.html