# Compiling external .java files from within Java

Tags: java, file, class, compilation

I am making a tool that will write .java files, then (hopefully) compile those files to .class files.  All in one process, the user selects a file directory where multiple .java files are written.  Now I want the program to compile these Java files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`JavaCompiler` is your friend. Check the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

And here an example on how you could use the compiler API

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("YouFileToCompile.java"));
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null,
        null, compilationUnits);
boolean success = task.call();
fileManager.close();
```

Comment: I tried this, and replaced the "YouFileToCompile.java" with an absolute path (problem?) now I get a NullPointerException at:

StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

Comment: Sounds like the `compiler` variable is `null`. Make sure you have a correct Java installation. Check this out for help http://www.java.net/node/688208

Comment: Does it have to be a .java file? If I have code in a .txt file, will it still work?

Comment: Also, if the code needs a dependency e.g. ASM, do I need to compile ASM with the app, or can I just have it in my main application?

Answer (score 6):

The `JavaCompiler` will be `null` if the code is running from a JRE.  It needs a JDK, which includes the `tools.jar`.