# Java - Run a string as normal code

Tags: java, string, runnable

Is there a way to run a string as code? I mean if I had a string run having value `System.out.println("Hello World)` could I run the string as normal code the then output will be Hello World?

For Example:

```
String code = "System.out.println("Hello World)";

code.run(); //I know this doesn't work
```

Console:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Checkout my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8364016/782719

Comment: I don't want to compile a program I would like to run the String in the current

Comment: Even if `eval()` was in Java, this won't work. "Hello World" was not enclosed as a literal, you're missing a `"`. It will fail to compile for the syntax error then. Also, you forgot to escape the `"`s within the string.

Comment: Technically, anytime you compile a java file to a class, you are running a string as code. If you want to import a text file programatically and run it as code from your code, you would have to find a way to recompile it programmatically. I don't know if that is possible

Answer (score 1):

You want the equivalent of JavaScript's [`eval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp). There is no equivalent in Java.

Well, there *is* but it's not trivial.

You can generate the full source code of a class containing that code. Something like

```
public class StuffToDynamicallyCompile  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
       PUT STUFF HERE!
   }
}
```

And then programatically invoke the compiler, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22637676/2736496), or as stated in the comments: [How to compile .java file from within java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363904/how-to-compile-java-file-from-within-java-program)

Not a simple task. Perhaps there's a way to minimize your requirements, so you can allow an extremely limited set of commands, and just execute it with a switch ("if 'dothis' then call `doThis()`, else if 'doThat', call `doThat()`, etc.).